# error while executing dynamic sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, dynamic-queries

When i executing this dynamic query i am getting an error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 59
>   Incorrect syntax near '1'.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_getScheduleCactByClntId]  
@clientId nvarchar(50),
@fromDt nvarchar(50),
@toDt nvarchar(50),
@catid nvarchar(50),
@subcatId nvarchar(50),
@locId nvarchar(50),
@groupId nvarchar(50),
@cstcntrId nvarchar(50)
AS

BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(max)
    SET @SQL = 'select catid,particular,(grossblock1+grossblock2)grossblock,addition,disp,
            (grossblock1+grossblock2+addition+disp+reval)balance,
            accdepopbl,(depamt+(-1*depsd))depamt,(accdepopbl+(-1*depsd)+(-1*depsdfy))depsd,
            (accdepopbl+(depamt+(-1*depsd)) - ((accdepopbl+(-1*depsd)+(-1*depsdfy))))balancedep,
            ((grossblock1+grossblock2+addition+disp+reval)-((accdepopbl+(depamt+(-1*depsd)) - ((accdepopbl+(-1*depsd)+(-1*depsdfy))))))netbalcl,
            (grossblock1+grossblock2 - dpon)  netbalop
            from (
            select cat.catid, isnull(cat.name,'''')particular,
            isnull(sum(case when convert(varchar(10),ad.ast_use_dt,126) <  '''+@fromDt+''' then astdd.adjustval_src else 0  end),0)grossblock1,
            isnull(sum(case when convert(varchar(10),ad.ast_use_dt,126) =  '''+@fromDt+''' and (isnull(astdd.opdepcmp,0) > 0 or ad.chkold = 1 )   then astdd.adjustval_src else 0  end),0)grossblock2,
            isnull(sum(addtn.adtnval),0)addition,
            -1 * sum(isnull(sd.sdval,0))disp,
            (sum(isnull(astdd.accudepval,0)) -  sum(isnull(debl.depamt,0)))accdepopbl,sum(isnull(depc.depamt,0))depamt,
            -1 * isnull(sum(depsd.depamt),0)depsd,
            -1 * isnull(sum(depsdopn.depamt),0)depsdopn,
            -1* isnull(sum(depsdfy.depamt),0)depsdfy,
            0.00 ''reval'',
            sum(isnull(dpon.depamt,0))dpon
            from
            tbl_AssetDetails ad 
            inner join tbl_Category cat on ad.ast_cat = cat.catid
            inner join tbl_AssetDepDetails astdd on ad.arid = astdd.arid
            left join (select sum(depamt)depamt,arid  from tbl_AssetDepRecord dprc 
                       where convert(varchar(10),dprc.todt,126) <=  '''+@fromDt+''' and dprc.clientId = '+@clientId+'
                       group by arid )dpon on dpon.arid = ad.arid
            left join ( select sum(depamt)depamt,arid from tbl_AssetDepRecord dprc 
                        where convert(varchar(10),dprc.todt,126) > = '''+@fromDt+''' and convert(varchar(10),dprc.todt,126) < = '''+@toDt+''' 
                        group by arid) depc on depc.arid = ad.arid
            left join ( select sum(addidp.adjustval_src)adtnval,addi.arid from tbl_AssetDetails addi 
                        inner join tbl_AssetDepDetails addidp 
                        on addi.arid = addidp.arid
                        where convert(varchar(10),addi.ast_use_dt,126) > = '''+@fromDt+''' and convert(varchar(10),addi.ast_use_dt,126) <= '''+@toDt+'''
                        and addidp.cact_deprt >= 0 and addi.clientId = '+@clientId+' and isnull(addi.chkold,0) != 1 and isnull(addidp.opdepcmp,0) <= 0
                        group by addi.arid )addtn
                        on addtn.arid = ad.arid
            left join (select sum(adp.adjustval_src)sdval,sdp.arid 
                       from tbl_SaleDispose sdp
                       inner join tbl_AssetDepDetails adp
                       on sdp.arid = adp.arid
                       where convert(varchar(10),sdp.sdate,126) > = '''+@fromDt+''' and convert(varchar(10),sdp.sdate,126) < = '''+@toDt+'''
                       and sdp.clientId = '+@clientId+'
                       group by sdp.arid )sd on sd.arid = ad.arid
            left join ( select sum(depamt)depamt,arid from tbl_AssetDepRecord deb 
                        where convert(varchar(10),deb.todt,126) > = '''+@fromDt+''' and deb.clientId = '+@clientId+'
                        group by arid) debl on debl.arid = ad.arid
            left join ( select sum(depamt)depamt,arid from tbl_AssetDepRecord dprc
                        inner join tbl_Depreciation dp on dprc.did= dp.did and dp.descp=''Sale/Dipose''
                        where convert(varchar(10),dprc.todt,126) > = '''+@fromDt+''' and convert(varchar(10),dprc.todt,126) < = '''+@toDt+''' 
                        and dprc.clientId = '+@clientId+'
                        and dprc.arid in (select sdp.arid from tbl_SaleDispose sdp where convert(varchar(10),sdp.sdate,126) > = '''+@fromDt+''' and 
                        convert(varchar(10),sdp.sdate,126) < = '''+@toDt+''' and sdp.clientId = '+@clientId+' )
                        group by arid) depsd on depsd.arid = ad.arid
            left join ( select sum(depamt)depamt,arid from tbl_AssetDepRecord dprc
                        inner join tbl_Depreciation dp on dprc.did= dp.did 
                        where convert(varchar(10),dprc.todt,126) < = '''+@toDt+''' 
                        and dprc.clientId = '+@clientId+'
                        and dprc.arid in (select sdp.arid from tbl_SaleDispose sdp where convert(varchar(10),sdp.sdate,126) > = '''+@fromDt+''' and 
                        convert(varchar(10),sdp.sdate,126) < = '''+@toDt+''' and sdp.clientId = '+@clientId+' )
                        group by arid) depsdopn on depsdopn.arid = ad.arid
            left join ( select sum(depamt)depamt,arid from tbl_AssetDepRecord dprc
                        inner join tbl_Depreciation dp on dprc.did= dp.did 
                        where convert(varchar(10),dprc.todt,126) > = '''+@fromDt+''' and convert(varchar(10),dprc.todt,126) < = '''+@toDt+''' 
                        and dprc.clientId = '+@clientId+'
                        and dprc.arid in (select sdp.arid from tbl_SaleDispose sdp where convert(varchar(10),sdp.sdate,126) > = '''+@fromDt+''' and 
                        convert(varchar(10),sdp.sdate,126) < = '''+@toDt+''' and sdp.clientId = '+@clientId+' )
                        group by arid) depsdfy on depsdfy.arid = ad.arid
            where convert(varchar(10),ad.ast_use_dt,126) < = '''+@toDt+''' and ad.clientId = '+@clientId+' and astdd.cact_deprt >= 0 and cat.method!=0 AND '

    IF(@catid!=0)
    SET @SQL = @SQL +' ad.ast_cat='+@catid+' AND '
    IF(@subcatId!=0)
    SET @SQL = @SQL +' ad.ast_subcat='+@subcatId+' AND '
    IF(@locId!=0)
    SET @SQL = @SQL + ' ad.ast_loc='+@locId+' AND '
    IF(@groupId!=0)
    SET @SQL = @SQL +' ad.ast_grp='+@groupId+' AND '
    IF(@cstcntrId!=0)
    SET @SQL = @SQL +' ad.ast_costcen='+@cstcntrId+' AND '

    SET @SQL = @SQL +' 1 = 1  group by cat.catid,cat.name )x '

    PRINT @SQL
    EXEC sp_executesql @SQL
END
```

I executed the output of the `@SQL` variable ( which i got through the PRINT command ) it runs perfectly. Is there something which i am missing. This was executing perfectly before, i have made some changes in the query and now it all seems to be messed up! i have got to get this on production soon.

The part output of the @SQL is:

```
select catid,particular,(grossblock1+grossblock2)grossblock,addition,disp,
        (grossblock1+grossblock2+addition+disp+reval)balance,
        accdepopbl,(depamt+(-1*depsd))depamt,(accdepopbl+(-1*depsd)+(-1*depsdfy))depsd,
        (accdepopbl+(depamt+(-1*depsd)) - ((accdepopbl+(-1*depsd)+(-1*depsdfy))))balancedep,
        ((grossblock1+grossblock2+addition+disp+reval)-((accdepopbl+(depamt+(-1*depsd)) - ((accdepopbl+(-1*depsd)+(-1*depsdfy))))))netbalcl,
        (grossblock1+grossblock2 - dpon)  netbalop
        from (
        select cat.catid, isnull(cat.name,'')particular,
        isnull(sum(case when convert(varchar(10),ad.ast_use_dt,126) <  '2017-04-01' then astdd.adjustval_src else 0  end),0)grossblock1,
        isnull(sum(case when convert(varchar(10),ad.ast_use_dt,126) =  '2017-04-01' and (isnull(astdd.opdepcmp,0) > 0 or ad.chkold = 1 )   then astdd.adjustval_src else 0  end),0)grossblock2,
        isnull(sum(addtn.adtnval),0)addition,
        -1 * sum(isnull(sd.sdval,0))disp,
        (sum(isnull(astdd.accudepval,0)) -  sum(isnull(debl.depamt,0)))accdepopbl,sum(isnull(depc.depamt,0))depamt,
        -1 * isnull(sum(depsd.depamt),0)depsd,
        -1 * isnull(sum(depsdopn.depamt),0)depsdopn,
        -1* isnull(sum(depsdfy.depamt),0)depsdfy,
        0.00 'reval',
        sum(isnull(dpon.depamt,0))dpon
        from
        tbl_AssetDetails ad 
        inner join tbl_Category cat on ad.ast_cat = cat.catid
        inner join tbl_AssetDepDetails astdd on ad.arid = astdd.arid
        left join (select sum(depamt)depamt,arid  from tbl_AssetDepRecord dprc 
                   where convert(varchar(10),dprc.todt,126) <=  '2017-04-01' and dprc.clientId = 3
                   group by arid )dpon on dpon.arid = ad.arid
        left join ( select sum(depamt)depamt,arid from tbl_AssetDepRecord dprc 
                    where convert(varchar(10),dprc.todt,126) > = '2017-04-01' and convert(varchar(10),dprc.todt,126) < = '2018-03-31' 
                    group by arid) depc on depc.arid = ad.arid
        left join ( select sum(addidp.adjustval_src)adtnval,addi.arid from tbl_AssetDetails addi 
                    inner join tbl_AssetDepDetails addidp 
                    on addi.arid = addidp.arid
                    where convert(varchar(10),addi.ast_use_dt,126) > = '2017-04-01' and convert(varchar(10),addi.ast_use_dt,126) <= '2018-03-31'
                    and addidp.cact_deprt >= 0 and addi.clientId = 3 and isnull(addi.chkold,0) != 1 and isnull(addidp.opdepcmp,0) <= 0
                    group by addi.arid )addtn
                    on addtn.arid = ad.arid
        left join (select sum(adp.adjustval_src)sdval,sdp.arid 
                   from tbl_SaleDispose sdp
                   inner join tbl_AssetDepDetails adp
                   on sdp.arid = adp.arid
                   where convert(varchar(10),sdp.sdate,126) > = '2017-04-01' and convert(varchar(10),sdp.sdate,126) < = '2018-03-31'
                   and sdp.clientId = 3
                   group by sdp.arid )sd on sd.arid = ad.arid
        left join ( select sum(depamt)depamt,arid from tbl_AssetDepRecord deb 
                    where convert(varchar(10),deb.todt,126) > = '2017-04-01' and deb.clientId = 3
                    group by arid) debl on debl.arid = ad.arid
        left join ( select sum(depamt)depamt,arid from tbl_AssetDepRecord dprc
                    inner join tbl_Depreciation dp on dprc.did= dp.did and dp.descp='Sale/Dipose'
                    where convert(varchar(10),dprc.todt,126) > = '2017-04-01' and convert(varchar(10),dprc.todt,126) < = '2018-03-31' 
                    and dprc.clientId = 3
                    and dprc.arid in (select sdp.arid from tbl_SaleDispose sdp where convert(varchar(10),sdp.sdate,126) > = '2017-04-01' and 
                    convert(varchar(10),sdp.sdate,126) < = '2018-03-31' and sdp.clientId = 3 )
                    group by arid) depsd on depsd.arid = ad.arid
        left join ( select sum(depamt)depamt,arid from tbl_AssetDepRecord dprc
                    inner join tbl_Depreciation dp on dprc.did= dp.did 
                    where convert(varchar(10),dprc.todt,126) < = '2018-03-31' 
                    and dprc.clientId = 3
                    and dprc.arid in (select sdp.arid from tbl_SaleDispose sdp where convert(varchar(10),sdp.sdate,126) > = '2017-04-01' and 
                    convert(varchar(10),sdp.sdate,126) < = '2018-03-31' and sdp.clientId = 3 )
                    group by arid) depsdop
```

Comment: Can you paste the output of print statement in your question?

Comment: i have pasted the part output of the print statement. it has limit of around 4000 or 8000 characters i guess

Comment: what is the length of your query `len(@sql)` ?

Comment: And `PRINT` magically ends with line 59 which is supposed to contain that error from the message...

Comment: change the initial part of your query to `set @sql = convert(nvarchar(max), '')` + 'select catid...'

Comment: it's giving me length(@sql) = 4038

Comment: @Squirrel man you saved my life. that worked. but could you explain me the logic behind it? previously was it initialising with some garbage value or something??

Comment: Take another look at this query when you have time for it. It could be at least twice shorter. With way much fewer concatenations.

Comment: @NirajKumar, see my explanation in the posted answer

Comment: @IvanStarostin well i tried my best to keep it short. any suggestion?

Comment: `SUM(CASE WHEN <condition> THEN depamt ELSE NULL) sum1, SUM(CASE WHEN <another condition> THEN depamt ELSE NULL) sum2, ` - try to apply to last 3 left joins.

Comment: I don't think case alone would satisfy the condition. the condition is something more like IF id = 1 then check if in another table 5 and 6 exists for ID = 1 and then take SUM. it's a bit difficult to describe the logic here. This stored procedure used to calculate the Depreciation and taxation for financial period, so you can imagine the degree of complexity

Answer (score 0):

even though the variable @sql is declared as nvarchar(max), but the concatenate string `select catid ...` is not nvarchar(max) and it got truncated before able to assigned to @sql.

```
set @sql = convert(nvarchar(max), '')
          + 'select catid ...'
```

this will ensure the result of the concatenate string is nvarchar(max) before assigned to @sql variable

Also take note that how many character the PRINT function is able to print out depends on the settings in SSMS. whatever settings it is, there is a max, so for large dynamic query, you will have problem printing out full query

Comment: Thanks a lot. i never thought the query which is to be concatenated has some limit to it.